# Jmeter slave nodes

Tags: jmeter, nodes, slave

In a load test, does using Jmeter slave nodes increases the maximum number or virtual users than can be set, or it just distribute them among the virtual slave servers?
Suppose that for a given load test and computer the maximun number of virtual users that can be set for one instance of Jmeter is 450. If I configure three virtual slave nodes by using Vagrant and Oracle´s Virtual Box shall I be able to set 1350 virtual users (450 X 3) or the maximun number of VU will still be 450 but distributed in three virtual slave machines? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**By default it will be 1350 virtual users (450 X 3)** as JMeter remote (slave) engines are independently executing the same Test Plan

---

There is a trick you can play to have different remote engines to have different virtual users numbers by setting them using [__P() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

[image: JMeter Virtual Users set by Property]

Given above setup by default each remote engine will have 450 virtual users, but you can manipulate the value via *user.properties* file like:

```
users=100
```

or passing the property value via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jusers=100 -s ....
```

References:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- [JMeter Functions and Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)